# iPhone App - Communicate with Bluetooth Device

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I'm tasked with developing an iPhone app whose first bit of functionality is to connect to a bluetooth transmitting device, receive data from that device, and use that data to do other important things. The issue I'm having is that there doesn't seem to be any good sort of SDK to work with, so I'm thinking of using the GameKit framework to search for bluetooth transmitting devices, connect to the (correct) device, and to receive data from this device.

Bullet points:
- search for bluetooth device
- connect to bluetooth device
- receive data only from the device

Tips/advice?

Comment: One more thing to mention. The data being sent from the device will be 22 bytes long I believe; what's the most efficient way to get/store that data?

Answer (score 3):

Apple doesn't let just any Bluetooth device to connect to an iOS device. The device must be MFi compliant.

Assuming you've been tasked with writing the app to work with your company's product, start with signing up with the [MFi developer program from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

Assuming the opposite, that you've been tasked with writing the app to work with a third party device make sure the product is MFi compliant. Finding a "Made for iPhone" or "Made for iPad" logo on the device or packaging is likely to indicate it is MFi compliant.

From there you should investigate the External Accessory Framework. Try reading [External Accessory Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html)